# Is the leak in my garbage disposal or not?

Tags: garbage-disposal

There's a leak under my sink. I've not been able to find any cracks in my garbage disposal. If I fill the sink with water and let it all out at once then something is spraying under the sink and it's not clear where the origin of the leak is. I've looked at some Youtube videos and the problem can be in one of a number of places. It could be the garbage disposal or a hose or pipe to it or a gasket.

I don't mind buying a new garbage disposal and I don't mind paying a plumber to replace it. What I want to avoid is having the plumber charge me for two visits. If I replace the disposal (it's nearly 20 years old) will that fix all likely sources of the leak such that the plumber will have spare gaskets and other parts to fix any other leak source in one visit? Is there a way I can pinpoint the source of the leak?

Comment: Start by Plugging the hole in your sink that leads to your garbage disposal. Fill your sink with water. Take a look at the underside of the sink, above the garbage disposal. If the underside of the sink has begun to leak, this is an indication that the putty that seals the sink flange has begun to deteriorate. I expect that is where your problem is. if not wrap each joint with newspaper and let the water out. See which paper is wet and you know the leaking joint.

Comment: Brilliant idea. Thank you!

Comment: *"something is spraying under the sink and it's not clear where the origin of the leak is"*... you need to get under there with a flashlight while it is "spraying" and pinpoint the source. Don't waste your time speculating.

Comment: You have the plumbing work backwards.  You have the plumber come to find and fix the leak and then if you want, replace the disposal, if you use a plumber.  Once you find the problem, good chance it will be simple repair and/or replace job you can do yourself.

Comment: All of that, including replacing the disposal, is simple enough to do without a plumber.

Comment: @GregNickoloff  Some of us tinkerers agree, but I can guarantee that a huge percentage of the population has no idea how to unscrew the trap cleanout cap, let alone do actual plumbing work.

Comment: Absolutely, @CarlWitthoft! Consider my comment an encouragement to them rather than any kind of admonishment.